# CDI web application not deployed properly on WildFly

Tags: ejb, cdi, wildfly

I'm working with a web application using ejb, cdi, maven, netbeans and wildfly 8.1 server.

Sometimes when I do clean/build, manually remove the content of the server path `wildfly-8.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments` and then try to run the ear file all works ok but when I load a web page I have the next error:

summary error:

```
com.mycompany.controller.CarController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getCarType(Unknown Source)
```

complete error:

```
16:26:17,215 FATAL [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-1) /pages/myPage.xhtml @30,87 value="#{myController.carType}": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.mycompany.ejb.facade.CarsFacadeLocal field com.mycompany.jsf.controller.MyController.carFacade to com.mycompany.ejb.facade.CarFacadeLocal$1909108192$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$: javax.faces.FacesException: /pages/myPage.xhtml @37,87 value="#{myController.carType}": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.mycompany.ejb.facade.CarFacadeLocal field com.mycompany.jsf.controller.MyController.carFacade to com.mycompany.ejb.facade.CarFacadeLocal$1909108192$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:84) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449) [shiro-web-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365) [shiro-web-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90) [shiro-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83) [shiro-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383) [shiro-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362) [shiro-web-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: /pages/myPage.xhtml @62,87 value="#{carController.carType}": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.mycompany.ejb.facade.CarFacadeLocal field com.mycompany.controller.CarController.carFacade to com.mycompany.ejb.facade.CarFacadeLocal$1909108192$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:988) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1249) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewParameter.processValidators(UIViewParameter.java:278) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1258) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1258) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    ... 40 more
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.mycompany.ejb.facade.CarFacadeLocal field com.mycompany.jsf.controller.CarController.carFacade to com.mycompany.ejb.facade.CarFacadeLocal$1909108192$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:368) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.mycompany.ejb.facade.CarFacadeLocal field com.mycompany.jsf.controller.CarController.carFacade to com.mycompany.ejb.facade.CarFacadeLocal$1909108192$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:94) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:358) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:369) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:72) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:60) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector$1.proceed(DefaultInjector.java:66) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:64) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:90) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:150) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:98) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:78) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at com.mycompany.controller.CarController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getCarType(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    ... 60 more
```

That's awful! I can't work...
What's going on?

Comment: Do you need to use an EAR? This issue happens when trying to deploy EARs at times.. really painful process.  Each JAR/WAR within is generally considered to be a separate application from CDI standpoint.

Comment: I use an enterprise application that contains 4 modules: MyApp-ear, MyApp-ejb, MyApp-web, MyApp-api. what do you recommend. I have ported the application because I was using managed beans before and I need to use omnifaces, cdi is mandatory to the future. What do you recommend?

Comment: I would just create a WAR file, and include your libraries within that.

Comment: Could you explain how can I do this on Netbeans? I'm using -> click on new Proyect->Maven->Enterprise Application. And run the app over the ear module.

Comment: Do you have some duplicated jars / classes on classpath?

Comment: @ctomc in fact your observation is common generating that problem, ear file can have a .jar as ear module and pom.xml in web application in the ear does not put that jar as provided. Good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you need to run over the web project and works.

right click over web project-> run